# vmlinuz...-generic has invalid signature when installing Ubuntu on a machine that has Windows and ElementaryOS dual-boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel, elementary

My machine was on dual-boot with Elementary OS and Windows 10. Today I also installed Ubuntu 18.04 on it. These are my boot options now:

[image: 1]

Ubuntu and Windows boot just fine, but 
when I try to boot Elementary OS Freya, I get the error:

```
error: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-141-generic has invalid signature.
error: you need to load the kernel first.
```

When I go to `Advanced Options for Elementary OS Freya`, there is a huge list of options shown, which is very odd:

[image: 2]

All these options show the same error. How can I boot Elementary OS?

These are the boot settings in BIOS Setup settings:

[image: 3]

**PS:** Secure Boot in BIOS settings is already disabled.

Comment: I don't know your issue, however when I've had Ubuntu not recognizing another OS during `update-grub`, being lazy and wanting only to quickly resolve the situation, I just `mount` the necessary partitions somewhere, and run `update-grub` again. It fixed it for me.  In your case I'd also explore looking for a no-longer used partition that was maybe once used for /boot/ for a 16.04 based system that is no longer used, and is just confusing `update-grub` - but that's guess.

Comment: @guiverc you might be right, I did have a Ubuntu 14.04 before which has been removed some years ago.

Comment: @guiverc I added a photo of Boot options in BIOS settings. Is that second Ubuntu option what you were referring to?

Comment: @guiverc It's strange that Elementary is not even shown there, though

Comment: First houseclean all those kernels or report will be long. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels You may need to use rEFInd or Supergrub to boot your elementary install. Do you have separate /EFI/elementary or does it use /EFI/ubuntu in ESP? May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score -1):

I just turned off Secure Boot in the BIOS/UEFI settings. You can also disable the same by disabling the secure boot option. (you can enter the boot menu using F2 and checkout Advanced Mode setting for secure boot options). It does work.